# can someone tell me if my MIPs translation into english is good?

Tags: assembly, syntax, mips

```
sll $t0, $s0, 2     #$t0 = f*4
add $t0, $s6, $t0   #$t0 = A[0+f]
sll $t1, $s1, 2     #$t1 = g*4
add $t1, $s7, $t1   #$t1 = B[0+g]
lw $s0, 0($t0)      #f = A[f], f becomes base array value of A + 0 
addi $t2, $t0, 4    #$t2 = A[f+4]
lw $t0, 0($t2)      #A[f] = A[f+4], (the stuff located at the base value of A[f+4+0] is stored in A[f])
add $t0, $t0, $s0   #A[F] = f(which == A[f])
sw $t0, 0($t1)      #B[g] = A[f]
```

im just learning MIPS and i think the stuff i have listed after the comments '#' is right but my mips compiler isnt working on it. no, im not exactly sure what the code is supposed to do. i got it in class and im simply trying to translate it so i can know whats going on, as the assignment is to simplify the code to less MIPs instructions. thanks.

Comment: (homework spoiler alert): Interestingly, gcc5.4 (https://godbolt.org/z/15A-fR) also wastes an `addiu` on the `f+1`, instead of using a non-zero offset in the addressing mode.  (But it does `f+1` first, and then addresses `A[f]` with `lw $2, -4($4)`.  But clang spots the one optimization this code is missing.  I was wondering if I was missing something, but no, unless compilers also missed it, the only optimization is folding an `addi` into an addressing mode displacement.

Comment: not really sure what you mean, mind if you clarify?

Comment: Click on the Godbolt link to see how clang compiles a function that does the same thing as this, with one fewer `add` instruction.  Or not, if you want to solve your homework on your own.

Comment: ok thank you i will try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming on input you have integer values `f` and `g` in `$s0` and `$s1` and pointers to the arrays `A` and `B` in in `$s6` and `$s7`, and those are arrays of 4-byte integers, then this is:

```
sll $t0, $s0, 2     # $t0 = f*4
add $t0, $s6, $t0   # $t0 = &A[f]
sll $t1, $s1, 2     # $t1 = g*4
add $t1, $s7, $t1   # $t1 = &B[g]
lw $s0, 0($t0)      # $s0 = A[f]
addi $t2, $t0, 4    # $t2 = &A[f+1]
lw $t0, 0($t2)      # $t0 = A[f+1]
add $t0, $t0, $s0   # $t0 = A[f+1] + A[f]
sw $t0, 0($t1)      # B[g] = A[f+1] + A[f]
```

so all this code boils down to the single assignment `B[g] = A[f+1] + A[f]`

Comment: thanks a ton. havent been able to get a good answer anywhere else

Comment: @IsaakJohnson: don't forget to click the "accept" checkbox if an answers does answer your question.

Comment: and all your assumptions were correct. sorry i forgot to include that information